# Prove that if A~B then Sym(A)~Sym(B).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I tried to prove it with sets. Really, truly clumsy. I know |A|=|B|. Can I simply conclude that |A|!=|B|! => Sym(A)~Sym(B)?? (Sym(A) for a set A is the set of all bijections from A to A.)

Comment: I am really not sure what exactly I am expected, and proving this using cardinals seems too obvious..

Comment: I'm ignorant, what kind of a function is Sym?

Comment: Sym(A) for a set A is the set of all bijections from A to A. Permutations actually... I am sorry I should have mentioned it...

Comment: Are your sets finite?

Comment: Not necessarily...

Comment: Then you cannot use $|A|!=|B|!$.

Comment: I just got it... Thanks..

Comment: @Ofir: That's not quite true; but you are right. The notation $|A|!$ makes perfect sense in the case of an infinite set, but its definition is $|\operatorname{Sym}(A)|$, so the question essentially asks to prove that $|A|=|B|$ implies $|A|!=|B|!$.

Comment: Asaf, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: In the next question it is defined that |Sym(A)|=a! for |A|=a, even infinite. And I have to show that א0!=c where c is the continuum and א0 is the cardinality of a countable set. Any suggestion?

Comment: Meitar, your last question has been asked many times before on the site, and there are many ways to solve it. Most appear on previously asked questions.

Comment: I was looking for it and couldn't find it... Usually I manage to find questions here, which is why it is odd... 
However, I solved it using upper and lower bounds...

Comment: Denoting א0 as t, can I say t! is larger then t(t-1)=t*t=c, so as to set a lower bound of t! ?

Comment: Uh, $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. You should also avoid subtracting cardinals, since that's pretty much meaningless for infinite cardinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a bijection
$$f:A\rightarrow B.$$
Now take a permutation $\sigma \in Sym(A)$.

Show that $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$ is a permutation of $B$.

And then show that the map
$$Sym(A)\rightarrow Sym(B),$$ taking $\sigma$ to $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Are you sure you want the composition that way around?

Comment: Why is that a problem? HSN? 
I want to know...

Comment: I seem to have misread it. It should probably be $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$. The function $f$ isn't defined on $B$, so $\sigma\circ f$ can't be a permutation of B.

Comment: True, fixed it, thanks.